# Buscar valor de um método não estático da própria classe, num metodo jfieldtextFocusLost

Tags: java, return, método

Tenho um método criado por mim que faz o retorno de um boolean:

```
  public boolean ValidaNumero() {
    long valor;
    if(NIPCC.isFocusable()){

    if (NIPCC.getText().length() != 0 ) {
        try {
            valor = Long.parseLong(NIPCC.getText());
            return true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Este campo tem de conter 9 dígitos", "Informação", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            NIPCC.grabFocus();
            return false;

        }
    }
    if(NIPCC.getText().length() != 9){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Este campo tem de conter 9 dígitos", "Informação", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
    return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Agora no método predefinido do java pus a fazer a validação do número:

```
private void NIPCCFocusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                
    // TODO add your handling code here:


    ValidaNumero();

    if (!NIPCC.getText().substring(0, 1).equals("1") && !NIPCC.getText().substring(0, 1).equals("2")
            && !NIPCC.getText().substring(0, 1).equals("3") && !NIPCC.getText().substring(0, 1).equals("5")
            && !NIPCC.getText().substring(0, 1).equals("6") && !NIPCC.getText().substring(0, 1).equals("8")
            && !NIPCC.getText().substring(0, 1).equals("9")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "NIPC inválido!");
    }
```

A questão é que eu só quero que o programa prossiga caso o retorno do método ValidaNumero() seja true. Tentei utilizar 'nomeclasse.ValidaNumero()' para tentar saber que valor foi retornado, mas não estou a conseguir fazer.
Estava a pensar nalguma coisa do tipo:

```
do{ ValidaNumero();while(return false);
```

Há forma de o fazer?

Estou a tentar resolver outro problema que é o seguinte:

A ideia é saber se o que foi escrito num jFieldText não são caracteres e se tem exatamente 9 dígitos, mas estou com um problema:

```
public void ValidaNumero() {
        long valor;

        if (NIPCC.getText().length() != 9) {
            for (char letra : NIPCC.getText().toCharArray()) {
                if (letra < '0' || letra > '9') {


                }

            }
            NIPCC.requestFocus();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Este campo tem de conter 9 dígitos", "Informação", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
             }
        else{
            System.out.println("Contém 9 dígitos");
        }
    }
```

Quando insiro menos do que dois dígitos ou caracteres, esse código é rodado duas vezes e a mensagem de erro aparece duas vezes, sabem explicar-me porquê ?

Comment: pelo que percebo `do{ ValidaNumero();while(return false);` executa o método `ValidanUmero()` uma única vez, é esta mesmo a ídeia? Se for, porquê do ciclo (`loop`)?

Comment: Pois só executa uma vez, e é o que eu não quero. Eu quero loop até obter resposta true do método ValidaNumero().

Comment: Bem eu não percebi bem a ideia do método, mas se ele sempre que executa pede um valor ao usuário ou algo do gênero, então coloque `true` na condição do ciclo. :d

Comment: O método ValidaNumero() não pede nenhum valor ao usuário, simplesmente retorna true ou false conforme algumas condições. e eu quero algo que me vá buscar o valor retornado do método, para dizer se prossegue o programa ou não. Isto não funciona mas era algo do género: if(ValidaNumero() == true) continua o programa, else{ValidaNumero). Eu não estou a conseguir ir buscar o retorno do método ValidaNumero().

Comment: Mas o que não percebo é mesmo isso. Imagine que o método retorne `false` e não inicia o programa, qual o eventualidade que poderia lhe fazer mudar de resultado?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que vi nos comentários, você quer que algo fique em loop enquanto o método ValidaNumero for verdadeiro, correto?

Se for esse o caso, basta você colocar o código da seguinte maneira:

```
while( ValidaNumero() ) {
   // codigo que você quer que seja executado enquanto validaNumero() for verdadeiro (true)
}
```

Note que esse código funciona somente com a sua primeira versão da função ValidaNumero (a que retorna um boolean).